# Can I change the global port number without my.cnf file?

Tags: mysql, docker

I made the following mysql container in the docker.
`docker run -p 3307:3307 --name todolist -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todolist -e MYSQL_USER=allssu -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234 -d mysql`

However, I confirmed that the port of mysql on the docker is still 3306. So I tried to modify the port number in the `my.cnf` file in the `/etc/mysql` path. But, only the `conf.d` file exists in the /etc/mysql folder, and there is no my.cnf file.

To make matters worse, an error occurs in my bash that the apt-get command does not work.

```
bash-4.4# apt-get update
bash: apt-get: command not found
bash-4.4# apt-get install vim
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

First, I want to find the invisible my.cnf file in the etc/mysql folder. Also I want to set the port of this container(name:todolist) to 3307, is there any way?

And, I want to use the vi command in bash.

I would appreciate it if you could consider this matter together.

Comment: I tried to connect the computer's port 3307 to the docker port 3307. But does it mean that the docker port is connected to 3306 instead of 3307?

Comment: The two port numbers don't need to agree.  You can set `-p 3307:3306` to forward host port 3307 to the standard MySQL port 3306, without reconfiguring the database.

Answer (score -2):

I tried the following and still couldn't find my.cnf.

```
bash-4.4# mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 'Default options'
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

result:

```
bash-4.4# pwd
/etc/mysql
bash-4.4# ls
conf.d
```

Comment: This seems more like something that should have been edited into the question. It doesn't answer your question. Please consider deleting it and editing this into the question.